# Creating a color bar for a graph that does not contain a mappable?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to add a [`colorbar`](https://matplotlib.org/api/colorbar_api.html) to a graph created by the Python library `matplotlib` that does not contain a "`mappable`". From what I can tell a `mapable` is some sort of object, such as a contour, which has discrete values on which a `colormap` can be mapped. Though in my case I am programmatically generating calls to `plot` (lines) that are not contained in a `mappable` object. I don't see a constructor/method for `colorbar` that does not assume a `mappable` object exists in the plot already.

My graph so far looks like (I can't seem to get an good image, but I think this works; yes its a horrible color scheme)

[image]

Here is a SSCCE of code to generate a graph like in the manner I am for the problem

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
from matplotlib.backends.backend_pdf import PdfPages

colorDict = {'red': [(0.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)], 'green': [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)], 'blue': [(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)]}
rgColorMap = LinearSegmentedColormap('RedGreen', colorDict, 10)
seedColors = cm.get_cmap(rgColorMap, 10)

graphPdf = PdfPages('Example.pdf')
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), dpi=100)
for lineInd in range(1, 9):
    plt.plot([x for x in range(1, 10)], [y*lineInd for y in range(1, 10)], color=seedColors(lineInd))

graphPdf.savefig(fig)
graphPdf.close()
```

**In this case how can I create a `colorbar` without having a `mappable` object being plotted?**

Is my only solution to group the data I am plotting in the loop into a `mappable` and then plotting after the loop has finished, or is there a way to instantiate a `colorbar` without some sort of `mappable`?

Comment: No worries, I'll delete the unclear additional question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course create your own ScalarMappable,

```
sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=...)
```

which would then need to have an array mapping to colors (`sm.set_array()`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors
import numpy as np

colorDict = {'red': [(0.0, 1.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)], 'green': [(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)], 'blue': [(0.0, 0.0, 1.0), (1.0, 0.0, 0.0)]}
rgColorMap = matplotlib.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap('RedGreen', colorDict, 10)
seedColors = plt.cm.get_cmap(rgColorMap, 10)

sm = plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=seedColors)
sm.set_array(range(1, 9))
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(8.27, 11.69), dpi=100)
for lineInd in range(1, 9):
    plt.plot([x for x in range(1, 10)], [y*lineInd for y in range(1, 10)], color=seedColors(lineInd))


fig.colorbar(sm, ticks=range(1,9), boundaries=np.arange(0.5,9,1))

plt.show()
```

[image]